# Center an horizontal scrolling section with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a horizontal scrolling page, I need to create a submenu that links to all subsections. I can't figure it out how to center the page on the div of the section clicked. The function I'm working with is not scrolling at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollContainer = $(".scrolling-wrapper");
    $('.rel_link').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var section = $("h2").attr('id', id).parent();
            // Scroll
            scrollContainer.animate({"scrollLeft": $(section).position().left}, 400);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.scrolling-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section_mono{
  flex: 0 0 100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-mono">                    
<span class="mono_link">
<a class="rel_link" id="one" href="#one" aria-label="go to sub-section">One</a>
<a class="rel_link" id="two" href="#two" aria-label="go to sub-section">Two</a>
</span>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
<div class="section_mono">
<h2><a class="s_link" id="one">One</a></h2>

<p>Text text text</p>
</div>
<div class="section_mono">
<h2><a class="s_link" id="two">Two</a></h2>

<p>Text text text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you've duplicated the `id` attributes, so it's getting the `position().left` of the `a` elements, not the `a` elements you're attempting to target. Id must be unique within the DOM, so remove that attribute from the `.rel_link` elements being clicked on.

The second issue is that you're setting the `id` attribute of the `h2`, not selecting by the `href` target of the clicked element.

With those issues fixed, the code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollContainer = $(".scrolling-wrapper");

  $('.rel_link').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    
    scrollContainer.animate({
      "scrollLeft": $(id).position().left
    }, 400);
  });
});
```

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section_mono {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head-mono">
  <span class="mono_link">
    <a class="rel_link" href="#one" aria-label="go to sub-section">One</a>
    <a class="rel_link" href="#two" aria-label="go to sub-section">Two</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="s_link" id="one">One</a></h2>
    <p>Text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section_mono">
    <h2><a class="s_link" id="two">Two</a></h2>
    <p>Text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's strange: it works perfectly fine in the code example, but when I'll go implementing it on the real code sometime it works, some others not. I need to see better if there is something different in the real code (I've already removed the `id` on the `.rel_link`)

Comment: Understood! I need to write this

`scrollContainer.animate({"scrollLeft": $(id).position().left + scrollContainer.scrollLeft()}, 400);`

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also ensure that you're running the jQuery code at a point the DOM has loaded - either in a document.ready handler (not included in the example as it's standard jQuery), or in a `<script>` tag placed just before the `</body>`